# Programmatically setting Application Insights instrumentation key throws error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

To support **Application Insights** in multiple environments, we are setting the *Instrumentation Key* programmatically, as adviced in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions.aspx).

We have left `<InstrumentationKey>` in ApplicationInsights.config empty, and instead added an application setting in **web.config**:

```
<add key="ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey" value="1234-5678-9xxx" />
```

In **Application_Start** we do the following to set the instrumentation key:

```
var instrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey"];

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instrumentationKey))
{
    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Missing app setting 'ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey' used for Application Insights");
}

TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;

new TelemetryClient().TrackEvent("Application started");
```

However, this produces an exception saying "**TelemetryChannel must be initialized before it can send telemetry**".

Googling this exception message yields nothing, but I guess there's something additional required before events can be tracked?

Comment: This might be because of the empty `<InstrumentationKey>` element in ApplicationInsights.config. Removed the element completely, and it seems to work now.

Comment: This blog post helped me to clear up some details: http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/06/09/do-not-use-context-initializers/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Removing the `<InstrumentationKey />` element from ApplicationInsights.config seems to do the trick.

I've done the exact same thing, setting the iKey in Application_Start() for a web application, and before I new() up a TelemetryClient in console applications.  I do *not* have any  element in my ApplicationInsights.config, not even a blank one.  I keep a comment in that config file that says the key is being set programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the element must be removed completely, which is kind of odd?

Comment: This was my experience as well.